# SQL Join 4 tables display select columns with row data

Tags: sql, join, select, disambiguation

I am trying to join 4 tables using SQL. The tables are

- "Article" (Primary key "a_id", "title", "au_id", "i_id")
- "Author" (Primary key "au_id", "name")
- "Issue" (Primary key "i_id", "j_id", "number")
- "Journal" (Primary key "j_id", "title")

I want to display article title, author, journal and issue. Atm it only displays
author and issue. However the data seems to be in the row, just not showing. Current code:

```
const sql = "SELECT a.a_id, a.title, j.title, iss.number, au.name
FROM Article AS a 
INNER JOIN Author AS au ON a.au_id = au.au_id 
INNER JOIN Issue AS iss ON a.i_id = iss.i_id 
INNER JOIN Journal AS j ON iss.j_id = j.j_id";
```

Comment: Why sb should alias a nice and human-readable name like `author` to `a`?

Comment: @HamidHaghdoost - to save having to type out `author` all the time? It's common practice - although the alias for `author` is `au` not `a`

Comment: Please supply some sample data (NOT an image), your actual results from that data and your expected results

Comment: @CHill60  as you saw in my comment, it is likely to be confused about the names. As you said, it is common practice, but in my opinion, it is not a good practice.

Comment: @HamidHaghdoost, something that you don't like doesn't make it a bad practice. For example, from my point of view it is a very good practice.

Comment: Start by joining just one table and build from there. Perhaps you need left joins if data are not found in all tables. Then in your select, you can coalesce like `coalesce(j.title, 'not found') as journal_title`.

Answer (score -1):

Ensure your data is properly structured to deliver the result you want

```
SELECT a.a_id As Articleid
a.title AS ArticleTitle, 
au.name AS AuthorName, 
j.title AS JournalTitle, 
iss.number AS IssueNumber
FROM Article AS a
 INNER JOIN Author AS au 
 ON a.au_id = au.au_id
  INNER JOIN Issue AS iss 
  ON a.i_id = iss.i_id
   INNER JOIN Journal AS j 
   ON iss.j_id = j.j_id;
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the OP's query just with aliases for the columns in the results